# Firestore DB in Native mode document write limit

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore database in Native mode has a limit of 1 "write" per document per second (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).

Does a document `delete` count as a `write` operation? i.e. if within a second we created a new document & then deleted it would we run into issues due to this limit?

In the billing documentation it talks about `reads`, `writes` & `deletes` making it sound as though a `write` and `delete` are separate types of  operations (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deletes *do* count as writes. The write limit is about sustained load
>   -- if you have a small burst of > 1/sec it's fine, but sustained > 1/sec will cause problems.

Quoted from a Google Firebase developer on Twitter: https://twitter.com/mbleigh/status/1158411267284934657

I have carried out a load test of 10,000 document creates followed by deletes in series over 400s (avg. 40ms per create -> delete) and noticed no impact (no errors or extra latency).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. A `delete` does count as a `write` operation in Firestore.

> Deletes do count as writes. The write limit is about sustained load -- if you have a small burst of > 1/sec it's fine, but sustained > 1/sec will cause problems.

Comment: I've tested this now and confirm that you can make a create a document and then delete it immediately i.e. in 30ms

Comment: unfortunately this is incorrect, just had a Google Firebase developer come back - will post another answer with his response. Thanks for taking the time in any case :)

Comment: Oh wow. This is new to me. Makes sense though. Thanks for finding the correct answer! I have revised my answer above.